# Thorough treatment of prime ends in a text

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a text which gives a thorough treatment of prime ends.  I am aware that Collingwood and Lohwater's *The Theory of Cluster Sets* has a chapter on the subject (and I am waiting on it through inter-library loan!).  Is there a text which gives a better treatment of the subject out there?

EDIT 1:
Let $D$ be a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  A *cross cut* $\gamma$ of $D$ is a path through $D$ both of whose end points are on $\partial D$.  Each cross cut ``cuts'' $D$ into two pieces.  A prime end is a sequence of cross cuts $\{\gamma_n\}$ such that:

1) For each $N>0$, the sequence $\{\gamma_n\}_{n>N}$ are all contained in one of the pieces of $D$ (with respect to $\gamma_N$).

2) The sequence converges to a point in $\partial D$.

Actually, the prime end is an equivalence class of such sequences.  You really have to look at some pictures of different kinds of prime ends to really understand why they are of any interest!

EDIT 2: I also just found that my copy of Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable II* contains a treatment of the subject.

Comment: I'd benefit from a definition or link to a definition of "prime ends".

Comment: @hardmath Added a definition, though as I said, you can't really get an idea of why they are interesting without looking at some pictures; a quick google image search was **completely** unsuccessful.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Goluzin has some prime ends/accessibility, but I wouldn't call it thorough, especially from the topological perspective.  It's sufficient for Caratheodory's Thoeorem and the like.  I have the Cluster Set book and it has a bit more, but it's also not very thorough.  Sadly, Wilder's "Topology of Manifolds" is probably the most thorough *book* on accessibility, but it's quite old and is exclusively topological - the most thorough from the complex perspective is also very old (1951), a monograph by Ursell and Young which I found tough to read unless you already know what you're doing.

Comment: I think that Pomerenke's book has some, as well, but I could be misremembering.  It's certainly his sort of topic.